# How do I convert a large list of dictionaries into a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I would like to create a dataframe from 9 million + dictionary records:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'movie1': {'user1': '2', 'user2': '4'},
                             'movie2': {'user2': '5'},
                             'movie3': {'user1': '2'}})
```

I've attempted using pd.DataFrame() which doesn't work due to the size.

Output I would like:

[image: dataframe with user1, user2 as index, movie... as columns]

Answer (score 1):

Simply feed it to the DataFrame constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

output:

```
      movie1 movie2 movie3
user1      2    NaN      2
user2      4      5    NaN
```

used input:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict, {'movie1': {'user1': '2', 'user2': '4'},
                       'movie2': {'user2': '5'},
                       'movie3': {'user1': '2'}})
```

Comment: Thanks mozway, I tried that. I should've mentioned it. It doesn't work due to the size of the dictionary.

Comment: Then I'm afraid what is limiting is your RAM… did you get an error message?

Comment: It definitely is a RAM, I'm working on ancient hardware. Running if off Google Colab. Been trying to figure out chunking with a dictionary. Found some interesting code using np.tile() but it's still a little greek to me.

Comment: chunking won't help you building the final dataframe, unless you're happy with several smaller dataframes?